# How to handle links to mobile sites that have desktop versions?

Tags: discussion, mobile-web

Every now and then I came across an answer which has link to Wikipedia, but the link is to the mobile version of the site. To me the jump from desktop SO to mobile wiki page is jarring, but I don't want to edit link without knowing the preferred way to handle this. Note that this question applies to all websites that have mobile versions.

**How should we handle situation where link points to mobile version, and main desktop version of the same resource is available?**

- Always edit links to point to main site.
- Leave answer as it is, but prefer links to main site, when posting new content.
- Always prefer mobile site. (Why?)

Ideally SO would handle this automatically depending on which version of SO is used, but that is probably not realistic option.

Answer (score -2):

Why edit the existing link?

Edit the answer to add a note to the link that it's directing to the mobile version of Wikipedia....then add an **extra** link to the desktop version of the Wikipedia page?

Enhancement all round.

Comment: I think this is the best option, assuming that it isn't possible in those cases to get/edit the content from the wikipedia article in the post it self (with proper attribution)

Comment: How would you handle this gracefully when link is, for example, part of the sentence? Also, if answer is long and has many links, and only some of those need two versions, it could become messy really fast.

Comment: Totally disagree. The last thing you need to be adding into answers is noise and redundant links. They link to *exactly the same content*, so there is no added value in having two links. If you want a different version of the page, then you can change it yourself.

Comment: You have to treat each one on it's merits. There's no blanket solution.